# Conditional Include With Linq to Entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Hopefully, this question has an easy answer and it is simply escaping me at the moment.

If I have a query like...

```
from p in context.Parents select p;
```

...and I also have the query...

```
from p in context.Parent.Include("Children") select p;
```

...what is the *best* way to conditionally include the call to the Include method?  By this, I would like to use the same query to handle both conditions (with, say, a boolean flag like includeChildren).  It seems like I have done this in the past using the method syntax but the LINQ syntax is a bit more friendly with complex queries that include joins (in my opinion).

Comment: I worked with this a bit longer.  What I discovered is that if the call to the Include method is made before the actual query is constructed, the query will *ignore* the Include part once a join in the query is added.  If I add the Include after the query is built, this appears to work, albeit appearing a bit *clunky*.  Perhaps this is related to the provider I am using (MySQL).

Comment: As a side note, I really wish this question wouldn't have been marked as a duplicate without asking for additional detail.  It was assumed that it was a duplicate but it is not (or at least the information in the other question did not work).  As such, I cannot add an answer where the information will be more visible to anyone that has the same issue.